# "Please check your Internet connection" box will not go away

Tags: 20.04, gui

[image: This box]

This box cannot be removed in any way I've tried so far. I'm sure a reboot would fix it (it has before), but is there a way to get rid of this thing without rebooting?

My connection is fine, and I've restarted networking multiple times.

This thing is covering up the bottom line in my terminal, and it's really frustrating.

Comment: Can you do `ping 1.1.1.1` and paste the output for me?

Comment: Is it gnome? Are you using some kind of addon? Please be more specific about your system.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli whatever the default GUI is on 20.04 - that's what I'm using. I've not installed any kind of addons that I'm aware of.

Comment: @Nate looks pretty normal to me: `64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=14.9 ms` etc.